# Weight paint color influence in Blender

Tags: weight-painting

I know that with Blender weight paint, BLUE color means no influence. My question is : which color can only move the mesh and not deform it?

Comment: how do you want to move your mesh? Vert. Colors alone don't do anything, neither move nor deform, they are just factors for other operations, like modifiers, particle systems and some other.

Comment: I mean, I want to create a Walk animation for a robot. I don't want his torso ans hips to be deformed like a human. I just want the hip and torso bones to move the mesh.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with robotic and mechanical animation, you should assign every vertex of torso to the torso bone  ONLY, the hip vertices to the hip bone ONLY, and so on. As long as a group of vertices are assigned to a bone/vertex group ONLY, they will move exactly with their bone, without distortions and deformations (and the value of the weight is not important, you can set it to 1.0, but any other value is OK). Deformations will occour when there are difference between the weights of different vertices, which tipically occour when using automatic weighting. So use instead parenting with "empty groups" option, then select the hip vertex group, select all hip vertices and click "assign" under the vertex group properties tab. Do the same for all the others vertex groups.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I understand it now. It means left arm vertices to left arm bones only so that they are moved but not deformed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use deformation, you shouldn't use Vertex Groups at all. Bone parenting will always require less setup and when your model gets complex (let's leave out draw call argumentation here), or you use it a lot of times, cumputing times will be significantly less.
You need to keep your robot parts separate for this. Then select eg. a 
leg -> Shift select the armature, hit CTRL + Tab (to get into pose mode), select the bone that is supposed to move the body part and hit CRTL + P and choose bone parent. 
No weight paint, no Modifiers, just plain parenting.